# 405 Response for a POST request using flask server

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, flask, flask-restful

I have been trying to access a flask based python server inside my application using the following code:

```
baseURL = 'http://' + IP_Add_Server + ":" + PORT
postURL = baseURL + '/new-user'
data = {'username': user_id.get(),'password': password.get()}
r = requests.post(url=postURL, data=data)
```

The server side code is as follows:

```
@flask_app.route('/new-user', methods = ['POST'])
def adduser():
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        ID = request.form['username']
        Pswd = request.form['password']
        return Response(myDB.add_new_user(ID, Pswd))
    else:
        return Response('Wrong method', mimetype = 'text/plain')
```

The response I get for the same is 405. I tried using `params` instead of `data` but that didn't solve the problem.

Can someone suggest what the problem might be?

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is exactly what you're running? Because it works fine for me, returning a 200 reponse (not a 405) and `Wrong method` body (because your logic is looking for `PUT`). Despite the fact that you're checking for `PUT` in the conditional, your route is defined as a `POST` method, and you're calling it with `requests.post`. Are you sure you don't have one or the other as `PUT` in your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server is expecting a PUT request, not a POST.

You can fix the issue by either making a PUT request with `requests.put` or changing the server to accept POST with `if request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: The code is confusing, but actually the valid methods for that route are specified in the second argument to the `@flask_app` decorator. In this case, POST is the only valid method.

Comment: @cody yeah i kind of just figured that was a typo since the code in the block under `if request.method == "PUT"` will never be reached if PUT isn't even allowed on the route